# Apache Server Won't start (Bitnami Redmine Stack - 2.0-3-1)

Tags: authentication, tortoisesvn, redmine, bitnami

I have been trying to get my head around to make things work with Redmine and I have downloaded `TortoiseSVN 1.7.7` *(Build 22907 - 64 Bit (Subversion 1.7.5))*.

I have been able to add users to Redmine, add projects, link them with TortoiseSVN. But I hit a block when trying to add authenticated users with TortoiseSVN.

The problem seems to lie in some DSO files. I have been following the page
[Apache Based Server](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-serversetup-apache.html#tsvn-serversetup-apache-7) from TortoiseSVN manual to configure the Apache Server for user authentication.

The instructions from TortoiseSVN manual tell us

1. Using the windows explorer, go to the installation directory of
   Subversion (usually c:\program files\Subversion) and find the files
   `/httpd/mod_dav_svn.so` and `mod_authz_svn.so`. Copy these files to the
   Apache modules directory    (usually c:\program files\apache
   group\apache2\modules ).
2. Copy the file `/bin/libdb*.dll` and `/bin/intl3_svn.dll` from the Subversion installation directory to the Apache bin directory.

Now I DO NOT see the folder that instructions tell us. That is when I install TortoiseSVN manually myself, I do not see the file `libdb*.dll` and cannot find the directory `httpd/` under the installation folders of SVN.

When I did a search I found the required files under the bitnami stack!

```
G:\Program Files\BitNami Redmine Stack\subversion\bin
```

From here I follow the instructions and in the end end I restart the Apache Server, it will not start again. It keeps failing. Probably there is something wrong and my guess are the files that need to be copied. As I don't see them in the manual installation of Tortoise SVN. Rather in the bitnami stack.

Can someone help me out?

Comment: This belongs to Server Fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BitNami Redmine Stack already includes an Apache Server and a Subversion server. It is the Apache server that you use. You don't need to add those dll to the bin folder. You need to enable those modules though and add the appropriate configuration in the httpd.conf file.

You need to uncomment these modules in the httpd.conf file:

```
LoadModule dav_module modules/mod_dav.so 
LoadModule dav_fs_module modules/mod_dav_fs.so 
LoadModule dav_svn_module modules/mod_dav_svn.so  
LoadModule authz_svn_module modules/mod_authz_svn.so
```

And at the end add a `<Location>` section according to the guide that you mention above.

Comment: could you mind telling me how can I do that? Its such a large configuration file and hard to get hold of all the settings.